# How to add a CSS class on button click to hide a menu without blocking future interactions

Tags: html, css

I have a component that when one of the 5 navigation items are hovered on, a mega menu appears (and remains visible until loses focus or closed).

Currently, whenever the close button is clicked, I add a class of `display: none` to the mega-menu to hide from view. However, this means that the mega-menu cannot be re-opened (when a user hovers again).

How can I toggle these classes so that the button actually closes the mega-menu but doesn't impede future interactions?

```js
const desktopMegaMenu = document.querySelector('.mega-menu');
const desktopCloseBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn-desktop');

desktopCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    desktopMegaMenu.classList.add('hide');
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-height: 112px;
  
}

.nav-menu {
  min-height: 112px;
  padding-left: 5.6rem;
  padding-right: 5.6rem;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nav-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.nav-menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 47px;
  padding-bottom: 47px;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.mega-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
  top: 128px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-menu:hover + .mega-menu {
  visibility: visible; 
  opacity: 1;
}

.mega-menu:hover {
  visibility: visible; 
  opacity: 1;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="mega-menu">
This mega menu is visible when a nav item is hovered on, or the mega menu itself is being hovered on. 

The problem I am facing is that when the user closes to the mega menu (by adding display: none) - future interactions no longer display the mega menu.
    <button class="close-btn-desktop">Close mega menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pressing the close button, the menu no longer appears, because the newly added class hide always exists, so the display is also none after re-hover.

I added a piece of javascript for you to remove the hide class when hovering, as follows:

```js
const desktopMegaMenu = document.querySelector('.mega-menu');
const desktopCloseBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn-desktop');

desktopCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  desktopMegaMenu.classList.add('hide');
});

//New js
//Use to remove the hide class when hover
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');

navMenu.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  desktopMegaMenu.classList.remove('hide');
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-height: 112px;
}

.nav-menu {
  min-height: 112px;
  padding-left: 5.6rem;
  padding-right: 5.6rem;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nav-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.nav-menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 47px;
  padding-bottom: 47px;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.mega-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
  top: 128px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-menu:hover + .mega-menu {
  visibility: visible; 
  opacity: 1;
}

.mega-menu:hover {
  visibility: visible; 
  opacity: 1;
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="mega-menu">
This mega menu is visible when a nav item is hovered on, or the mega menu itself is being hovered on. 

The problem I am facing is that when the user closes to the mega menu (by adding display: none) - future interactions no longer display the mega menu.
    <button class="close-btn-desktop">Close mega menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest one solution :

So I mostly use js function and removed your hover state in css, so there's the same action in the same place.

You can use a new function to add your visible class when hover a nav item, then remove it by clicking the close button :

1: I added the "nav-link" class to your nav item ;

2: I added one function "mouseover" on the nav item to make the big menu appear, by adding a class "is-visible" and remove it by clicking on the close button;

3: I added the class "is-visible" in the css;

```js
const desktopMegaMenu = document.querySelector('.mega-menu');
const desktopCloseBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn-desktop');
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    desktopMegaMenu.classList.add('is-visible');
  })
});


desktopCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  desktopMegaMenu.classList.remove('is-visible')
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-height: 112px;
  
}

.nav-menu {
  min-height: 112px;
  padding-left: 5.6rem;
  padding-right: 5.6rem;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nav-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.nav-menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 47px;
  padding-bottom: 47px;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.mega-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
  top: 128px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* .nav-menu:hover + .mega-menu {
  visibility: visible; 
  opacity: 1;
} */

.is-visible {
  visibility: visible; 
  opacity: 1;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="mega-menu">
This mega menu is visible when a nav item is hovered on, or the mega menu itself is being hovered on. 

The problem I am facing is that when the user closes to the mega menu (by adding display: none) - future interactions no longer display the mega menu.
    <button class="close-btn-desktop">Close mega menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way, given your current approach, would be to remove the `hide` class from the element when the user moves the cursor back to the `.nav-menu`:

```js
const desktopMegaMenu = document.querySelector('.mega-menu');
const desktopCloseBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn-desktop');

// new variable, caching the '.nav-menu' element:
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');

desktopCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  desktopMegaMenu.classList.add('hide');
});

// using EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the anonymous
// Arrow function as the event-handler for the 'mouseenter'
// event:
navMenu.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  // here use the Element.classList API to remove the
  // 'hide' class from the desktopMegaMenu element:
  desktopMegaMenu.classList.remove('hide')
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-height: 112px;
}

.nav-menu {
  min-height: 112px;
  padding-left: 5.6rem;
  padding-right: 5.6rem;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nav-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.nav-menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 47px;
  padding-bottom: 47px;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.mega-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
  top: 128px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-menu:hover+.mega-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mega-menu:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="mega-menu">
    This mega menu is visible when a nav item is hovered on, or the mega menu itself is being hovered on. The problem I am facing is that when the user closes to the mega menu (by adding display: none) - future interactions no longer display the mega menu.
    <button class="close-btn-desktop">Close mega menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code:

```js
const desktopMegaMenu = document.querySelector('.mega-menu');
      const desktopCloseBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn-desktop');
const a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
      desktopCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        desktopMegaMenu.style.visibility = "hidden";
      });
      
a.forEach( element => {
      element.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        desktopMegaMenu.style.visibility = "visible";
      });
      });
```

```css
.container {
  max-height: 112px;
  
}

.nav-menu {
  min-height: 112px;
  padding-left: 5.6rem;
  padding-right: 5.6rem;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nav-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.nav-menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 47px;
  padding-bottom: 47px;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.mega-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
  top: 128px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-menu:hover + .mega-menu {
  visibility: visible; 
  opacity: 1;
}

.mega-menu:hover {
  visibility: visible; 
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Navigation item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="mega-menu">
This mega menu is visible when a nav item is hovered on, or the mega menu itself is being hovered on. 

The problem I am facing is that when the user closes to the mega menu (by adding display: none) - future interactions no longer display the mega menu.
    <button class="close-btn-desktop">Close mega menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope you find this useful!